# How to fopen with a varies filename of a .TXT file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
  $file = "sample_623fWB93.txt"; // change filename everyday
  $fp = fopen($file, "r");
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($file));
  fclose($fp);

  $sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  if (!$sql) {
      die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("textfile");

  $result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$file'" .
                        " INTO TABLE dv_payees FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'");
  if (!$result) {
      die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
  }
```

Is there a way to code in php that can read a generated random .txt filename that will varies everyday and it will automatically load in database. Example the text today is `sample_623fWB93.txt` then tom. the textfile will be `sample_9439BJD20.txt` then the day after tom. will be `sample_259KLG11.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Use simple `date` format:

```
$file = "sample_" . date("d_m_y") . ".txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
// other stuff
```

**Update**:
If your files have other name format, which is not like today's date - you should **find** a file in a directory. There're at least two ways:

1. Use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) function with some regexp parameter.

   ```
   foreach (glob("/path/to/reports/*.txt") as $filename) {
       echo $filename;
   }
   ```
2. If you're sure that there's only one file (or one `txt` file) in your directory - you can use [`opendir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) and [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and find it's name.

   ```
   $path = '/path/to/reports/';
   if ($dh = opendir($path)) {
       while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
           echo "File: $file : type: " . filetype($path . $file) . "<br />";
       }
       closedir($dh);
   }
   ```

Comment: tnx you sir, how about if the filename of textfile is random? like `sample_75823.txt` then tom. will be `sample_86304.txt`?

Comment: What is the logic with `75283` and `86304`? None?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the filename dynamically:

```
$base = 'sample_';
$extension = '.txt';
$dateFormat = 'd_m_y';
$file = $base . date($dateFormat) . $extension;
```

And you have the filename

Comment: tnx you sir, how about if the filename of textfile is random? like `sample_75823.txt` then tom. will be `sample_86304.txt`?

Comment: @DafnyCruz Then you could replace `$dateFormat` with two variables `$min` and `$max` that will contain the minimum and maximum numbers that can be randomly generated and use `rand($min, $max)` instead of `$date`. Read more about `rand` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php